# Linux crash DiscretizeRegion

Tags: mesh, crash, linux

Good evening,

can anyone confirm this bug on his/her Linux machine and Windows machine?

```
DiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[Region@Rectangle[{1200,-3028},{1800,-2428}], Region@Disk[{4822,-1220}, {3622,3016}, {Pi,2*Pi}]]
```

This is a simple region complement of a rectange and a bottom-half ellipse (I need to cut a ceramic tile for my backyard). RegionDifference is ok, but the discretizing fails without any message or warning; the kernel simply crashes. I'm running  `12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)` on `Kubuntu 20.10 64-bit, kernel 5.8.0-43`. Thanks!

Comment: (1) I don't get a crash on my Mac (which maybe you know, since you don't ask about Macs). (2) While the command works despite the syntax "error" that is indicated by the Front End, you might try the documented syntax without the `{}` around the regions: `DiscretizeRegion@RegionDifference[Region@Rectangle[{1200, -3028}, {1800, -2428}], Region@Disk[{4822, -1220}, {3622, 3016}, {Pi, 2*Pi}]]` (probably won't help, but worth a try).

Comment: Nope, still a "silent" crash :( -- removed the list; thanks for the info. Copy+Paste error.

Comment: No crash on Windows 10 12.2.0.0 - I ran it ten times.

Comment: I have a crash on `"12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"` on `Linux 4.19.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.171-2 (2021-01-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Gentoo Linux, Mathematica 12.2 , also crash if using `DiscretizeRegion`, so we have to use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`

Comment: I do observe a kernel crash on Mma 12.2.0, Fedora 32, kernel 5.10.19. The OP should report this to WRI,

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have reported it to Wolfram support.

Comment: Support case 4787601.

Comment: No crash on "12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug confirmed by Wolfram (on 09-MAR-2021). Suggested workaround: execute `DiscretizeRegion[Disk[]]` before running the regular code. I guess this is needed to do some initialization; and it does the trick ;-)